# feature selection from subset of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm working with a DNS traffic dataset where I have some relevant IPs (8 relevant users) that I want to filter its traffic. I have 100 json files that each one represents one day (session) of traffic. I want a matrix of occurrences from its values according to a column (dns_querty) because I'm training a ML algorithm with this data. Lets say I have the following columns:

[image]

The only relevant columns for me are the `dns_query` and `s_ip` which means that I have the source IP and the domain requested. To this end I've tried different ways but I'm stuck.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import json 

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, HashingVectorizer, TfidfTransformer, TfidfVectorizer

user1 = ['10.0.0.44'] # test with 1 user
real_users = ['10.0.0.44','10.0.0.60','10.0.0.33','10.0.0.32','10.0.0.42','10.0.0.31',
          '10.0.0.34','10.0.0.29'] #real users

flag = 0
f = '/content/drive/MyDrive/anon_dns_data' #folder with 100 files

#trying different feature selection methods
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
hash_vectorizer = HashingVectorizer()
tfidf_trans = TfidfTransformer()
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

try:
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(f):
      flag+=1 #flag to control the days of traffic
      for filename in files:
          files = os.path.join(root, filename)
          data = pd.read_json(files)
          print(files)
          columns = data.loc[:,['s_ip','dns_query']] #get only relevant columns
          subset = columns[columns["s_ip"].isin(user1)] #filter by ip
          print(subset[:50], subset.shape) #this line prints the image 2
          a = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(subset)
          b = hash_vectorizer.fit_transform(subset)
          d = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(subset)
          if flag == 1:
            break
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
#print(a.toarray(),a.shape)
b.toarray()
#print(b[50:])
#print(d.toarray(),d.shape)
```

The above image represents the domains requested by one user:

[image]

To be more specific, I want a matrix like the following example from sklearn, lets say we have a corpus with 4 elements (to me each element of the list represents a day of traffic that I'm treating as a dataframe):

[image]

where each row represents one day of traffic of one user only. Meaning that the first 8 rows of N number of columns (n requested domains) represent one day of traffic. So if I try with 10 days, this means that I should have a matrix of 8*10 = 80 rows by N columns. How can I achieve something like this and which class of feature selection/extraction of sklearn would fit my problem? Any help/guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: How did `dns_query` values go from an apparent *text* domain name (first image) to a *byte string* (second image)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Oh, sorry I didnt clarify this before, in the dataset there are also the DNS servers IP's. In this case 132.248.10.2 is the DNS server. In the second image the 10.0.0.44 is the end user, so the `dns_query` is obfuscated by the protocol itself. It really doesnt matter, at the end of the day it is a categorical variable that i would map (as 0 or 1) to feed the ML model.

Comment: In your code, is the reassignment of `files` intentional?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes! depending on the value of `flag` it will iterate over the directory to get each JSON file in `'/content/drive/MyDrive/anon_dns_data` In this case `if flag ==1` only gets the first file.

Comment: Does [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72459925/1409374) help?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thank you for your detailed answer. Nevertheless I tried something with your ideas with lambda, but not the way i want it to work. I actually dont need at all the tiemestamp at this point. Even i do not have spaces `" "` in the dataframe, but the matrix of the end is something similar to the matrix i want to make. Instead of having 37 rows, I want to have 1 row with 37 columns (`dns_queries`) that represent the queries from 1 IP

Comment: In my example, I used `timestamp` to group/partition my toy data into days ("one day of traffic"). You can partition your data however you like, but keep in mind it will affect the `CountVectorizer` results. I think you misunderstand the final array. Each row is for one day's worth of `dns_query` for one `s_ip`. Each column is a count for a unique `dns_query`. You can see how many unique `s_ip` and `dns_query` there are in my toy data. The resultant array are the count vectors for all `s_ip` and `dns_query` for each day. Note that in my toy data, not every `s_ip` made a `dns_query` everyday.

Comment: Thanks man, I think i have something in the way I want. Take a look at this sample [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WnUVZH6yTgwNiTfjRsXPhIySdrQKs7lB?usp=sharing). But why it returns a shape of 9 columns instead of 8? Also, i changed your line `X = vectorizer.fit_transform(new_df["dns_queries"].values)` to `X = vectorizer.fit_transform(new_df["s_ip"].values)` to get the s_ip as columns, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to use [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) on `dns_query` for the groups I think you want.

Python code summary:

1. import my toy DNS JSON records into `df`
2. `groupby` `s_ip` and day (`timestamp.date()`) into `df_groupby`
3. create `new_df` with groups and `join`'ed `dns_query` strings (`" "` separator)
4. `import CountVectorizer`
5. specify `vectorizer` with custom `tokenizer` to just split on white space
6. do the `fit_transform`
7. show the `X` array result

Some steps can be combined, etc., but I wanted to demonstrate the technique and show some intermediate results.  You will need to adapt this to your data.

N.B.:  If I understand the `CountVectorizer` properly, you will need to run it so that all possible `dns_query` strings are present somewhere when you run `fit_transform` (like I've done here), *or* you will need to specify a full `vocabulary` for `CountVectorizer` so that in the end a meaningful matrix can be generated.

```py
$ ipython
Python 3.10.4 (main, Mar 25 2022, 00:00:00) [GCC 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_json("dns_jq.json", orient="records")

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
               s_ip                dns_query                 timestamp
0    93.247.220.198     dynamicreal-time.org 2022-01-02 07:28:47+00:00
1    89.121.211.207   nationalintegrate.name 2022-01-02 22:01:08+00:00
2        94.6.90.22     productstrategic.org 2022-01-04 20:07:59+00:00
3   154.147.200.177  districtuser-centric.io 2022-01-02 08:21:11+00:00
4     50.104.137.53    dynamice-commerce.biz 2022-01-02 13:10:44+00:00
..              ...                      ...                       ...
95    77.236.52.126  districtinterfaces.info 2022-01-05 19:14:12+00:00
96   93.247.220.198   internalimplement.name 2022-01-04 02:18:44+00:00
97   89.121.211.207     globalsyndicate.name 2022-01-03 05:20:20+00:00
98       94.6.90.22     internalrepurpose.io 2022-01-04 01:05:23+00:00
99  154.147.200.177     dynamicreal-time.org 2022-01-01 17:21:45+00:00

[100 rows x 3 columns]

In [4]: df.s_ip.unique()
Out[4]: 
array(['93.247.220.198', '89.121.211.207', '94.6.90.22',
       '154.147.200.177', '50.104.137.53', '64.0.100.231',
       '55.209.226.216', '77.236.52.126'], dtype=object)

In [5]: df.dns_query.unique()
Out[5]: 
array(['dynamicreal-time.org', 'nationalintegrate.name',
       'productstrategic.org', 'districtuser-centric.io',
       'dynamice-commerce.biz', 'forwardintuitive.io',
       'corporateseize.org', 'districtinterfaces.info',
       'internalimplement.name', 'globalsyndicate.name',
       'internalrepurpose.io'], dtype=object)

In [6]: df_groupby = df.groupby(lambda k: (df.iloc[k].s_ip, df.iloc[k].timestamp.date()))

In [7]: df_groupby
Out[7]: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7f6eb79fea10>

In [8]: df_groupby.groups
Out[8]: {('154.147.200.177', 2022-01-01): [99], ('154.147.200.177', 2022-01-02): [3, 11, 19, 27, 51, 83], ('154.147.200.177', 2022-01-03): [67], ('154.147.200.177', 2022-01-04): [35, 43, 59, 75, 91], ('50.104.137.53', 2022-01-01): [28, 36, 52, 60], ('50.104.137.53', 2022-01-02): [4, 20, 44], ('50.104.137.53', 2022-01-03): [76], ('50.104.137.53', 2022-01-04): [12, 68, 84, 92], ('55.209.226.216', 2022-01-01): [6, 14, 30, 86], ('55.209.226.216', 2022-01-02): [38, 54, 70], ('55.209.226.216', 2022-01-03): [46, 78, 94], ('55.209.226.216', 2022-01-04): [62], ('55.209.226.216', 2022-01-05): [22], ('64.0.100.231', 2022-01-01): [29, 77], ('64.0.100.231', 2022-01-02): [37, 45, 53, 85], ('64.0.100.231', 2022-01-03): [21], ('64.0.100.231', 2022-01-04): [13, 61], ('64.0.100.231', 2022-01-05): [5, 69, 93], ('77.236.52.126', 2022-01-01): [47, 79], ('77.236.52.126', 2022-01-02): [15], ('77.236.52.126', 2022-01-03): [7, 23, 39], ('77.236.52.126', 2022-01-04): [31, 71, 87], ('77.236.52.126', 2022-01-05): [55, 63, 95], ('89.121.211.207', 2022-01-01): [17], ('89.121.211.207', 2022-01-02): [1, 41, 57], ('89.121.211.207', 2022-01-03): [9, 25, 33, 65, 73, 97], ('89.121.211.207', 2022-01-04): [81, 89], ('89.121.211.207', 2022-01-05): [49], ('93.247.220.198', 2022-01-01): [32], ('93.247.220.198', 2022-01-02): [0, 48, 56, 64, 80, 88], ('93.247.220.198', 2022-01-03): [8, 72], ('93.247.220.198', 2022-01-04): [24, 96], ('93.247.220.198', 2022-01-05): [16, 40], ('94.6.90.22', 2022-01-02): [42, 50, 74], ('94.6.90.22', 2022-01-03): [26, 90], ('94.6.90.22', 2022-01-04): [2, 10, 18, 58, 66, 98], ('94.6.90.22', 2022-01-05): [34, 82]}

In [9]: new_df=pd.DataFrame({"group": df_groupby.groups.keys(), "dns_queries":[" ".join(df.loc[k].dn
   ...: s_query.values) for k in df_groupby.groups.values()]})

In [10]: new_df
Out[10]: 
                            group                                        dns_queries
0   (154.147.200.177, 2022-01-01)                               dynamicreal-time.org
1   (154.147.200.177, 2022-01-02)  districtuser-centric.io dynamicreal-time.org i...
2   (154.147.200.177, 2022-01-03)                             nationalintegrate.name
3   (154.147.200.177, 2022-01-04)  productstrategic.org internalrepurpose.io dyna...
4     (50.104.137.53, 2022-01-01)  corporateseize.org districtuser-centric.io int...
5     (50.104.137.53, 2022-01-02)  dynamice-commerce.biz globalsyndicate.name dyn...
6     (50.104.137.53, 2022-01-03)                               internalrepurpose.io
7     (50.104.137.53, 2022-01-04)  nationalintegrate.name productstrategic.org di...
8    (55.209.226.216, 2022-01-01)  corporateseize.org districtuser-centric.io int...
9    (55.209.226.216, 2022-01-02)  forwardintuitive.io internalrepurpose.io dynam...
10   (55.209.226.216, 2022-01-03)  productstrategic.org nationalintegrate.name co...
11   (55.209.226.216, 2022-01-04)                            districtinterfaces.info
12   (55.209.226.216, 2022-01-05)                               dynamicreal-time.org
13     (64.0.100.231, 2022-01-01)       districtinterfaces.info dynamicreal-time.org
14     (64.0.100.231, 2022-01-02)  dynamice-commerce.biz nationalintegrate.name g...
15     (64.0.100.231, 2022-01-03)                               internalrepurpose.io
16     (64.0.100.231, 2022-01-04)            productstrategic.org corporateseize.org
17     (64.0.100.231, 2022-01-05)  forwardintuitive.io districtuser-centric.io fo...
18    (77.236.52.126, 2022-01-01)       districtuser-centric.io productstrategic.org
19    (77.236.52.126, 2022-01-02)                              dynamice-commerce.biz
20    (77.236.52.126, 2022-01-03)  districtinterfaces.info nationalintegrate.name...
21    (77.236.52.126, 2022-01-04)  globalsyndicate.name forwardintuitive.io inter...
22    (77.236.52.126, 2022-01-05)  dynamicreal-time.org internalimplement.name di...
23   (89.121.211.207, 2022-01-01)                                 corporateseize.org
24   (89.121.211.207, 2022-01-02)  nationalintegrate.name internalimplement.name ...
25   (89.121.211.207, 2022-01-03)  globalsyndicate.name districtuser-centric.io d...
26   (89.121.211.207, 2022-01-04)       dynamice-commerce.biz nationalintegrate.name
27   (89.121.211.207, 2022-01-05)                                forwardintuitive.io
28   (93.247.220.198, 2022-01-01)                               internalrepurpose.io
29   (93.247.220.198, 2022-01-02)  dynamicreal-time.org dynamice-commerce.biz nat...
30   (93.247.220.198, 2022-01-03)          internalimplement.name corporateseize.org
31   (93.247.220.198, 2022-01-04)        productstrategic.org internalimplement.name
32   (93.247.220.198, 2022-01-05)        forwardintuitive.io districtinterfaces.info
33       (94.6.90.22, 2022-01-02)  globalsyndicate.name corporateseize.org intern...
34       (94.6.90.22, 2022-01-03)         dynamice-commerce.biz productstrategic.org
35       (94.6.90.22, 2022-01-04)  productstrategic.org internalrepurpose.io dist...
36       (94.6.90.22, 2022-01-05)         nationalintegrate.name forwardintuitive.io

In [11]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [12]: vectorizer = CountVectorizer(lowercase=False, tokenizer=lambda s: s.split())

In [13]: X = vectorizer.fit_transform(new_df["dns_queries"].values)

In [14]: X.toarray()
Out[14]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```